# removing constexpr from a variable capturing a constexpr function return value removes compile-time evaluation

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, char-traits

Consider the following `constexpr` function, `static_strcmp`, which uses C++17's `constexpr` `char_traits::compare` function:

```
#include <string>

constexpr bool static_strcmp(char const *a, char const *b) 
{
    return std::char_traits<char>::compare(a, b,
        std::char_traits<char>::length(a)) == 0;
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr const char *a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    constexpr const char *b = "abc";

    constexpr bool result = static_strcmp(a, b);

    return result;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nIORGd) shows this gets evaluated at compile-time, and optimised down to:

> ```
> main:
>     xor     eax, eax
>     ret
> ```

**Remove `constexpr` from `bool result`:**

If we remove the `constexpr` from `constexpr bool result`, now the call is no longer optimised.

```
#include <string>

constexpr bool static_strcmp(char const *a, char const *b) 
{
    return std::char_traits<char>::compare(a, b,
        std::char_traits<char>::length(a)) == 0;
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr const char *a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    constexpr const char *b = "abc";

    bool result = static_strcmp(a, b);            // <-- note no constexpr

    return result;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vF9pAt) shows we now call into `memcmp`:

> ```
> .LC0:
>     .string "abc"
> .LC1:
>     .string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
> main:
>     sub     rsp, 8
>     mov     edx, 26
>     mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
>     mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
>     call    memcmp
>     test    eax, eax
>     sete    al
>     add     rsp, 8
>     movzx   eax, al
>     ret
> ```

**Add a short circuiting `length` check:**

if we first compare `char_traits::length` for the two arguments in `static_strcmp` *before* calling `char_traits::compare`, **without** `constexpr` on `bool result`, the call is optimised away again.

```
#include <string>

constexpr bool static_strcmp(char const *a, char const *b) 
{
    return 
        std::char_traits<char>::length(a) == std::char_traits<char>::length(b) 
        && std::char_traits<char>::compare(a, b, 
             std::char_traits<char>::length(a)) == 0;
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr const char *a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    constexpr const char *b = "abc";

    bool result = static_strcmp(a, b);            // <-- note still no constexpr!

    return result;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z7pBOs) shows we're back to the call being optimised away:

> ```
> main:
>     xor     eax, eax
>     ret
> ```

- Why does removing `constexpr` from the initial call to `static_strcmp` cause the constant evaluation to fail?
- Clearly even **without** `constexpr`, the call to `char_traits::length` is evaluated at compile time, so why not the same behaviour without `constexpr` in the first version of `static_strcmp`?

Comment: Does the second snipped accesses the `b` pointer out of bounds so it is undefined behavior? It is, [looks like](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L149) and [looks like](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L319) it's a plain memcmp. So it is undefined behavior.

Comment: The first case is the same problem as doing any other function call, the compiler doesn't have to optimize it away.

Comment: But the `__constant_char_array_p(__s2, __n)` inside `char_traits<char>::compare` will evaluate to false, beacuse `b[4]` is not a constant expression. So it may or may not be a constexpr, because it's undefined. The `compare` function is not `strcmp` it is `memcmp`, it doesn't stop on null termination characters.

Comment: Because constexpr functions are not guaranteed to be called at compile time unless their result is used in a context which requires constant expression. Than it just becomes a case of missing optimization, there are millions of those.

Comment: @SergeyA I guess that is the exact answer - thank you! If you want to put it in an actual answer I'll gladly accept

Comment: I feel this is relevant, if not a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181797/c-constexpr-function-in-return-statement

Comment: @StoryTeller I agree it is definitely relevant - thanks for the link!

Comment: @SteveLorimer done )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that nothing in the standard **explicitly** requires `constexpr` function to be called at compile time, see 9.1.5.7 in latest draft:

> A call to a constexpr function produces the same result as a call to
>   an equivalent non-constexpr function **in all respects** except that (7.1)
>   a call to a constexpr function can appear in a constant expression and
>   (7.2) copy elision is not performed in a constant expression
>   ([class.copy.elision]).

(emphasizes mine)

Now, when the call appears in constant expression, there is no way compiler can avoid running the function at compile time, so it dutifully obliges. When it does not (as in your second snippet) it is just a case of missing optimization. There is no shortage of those around here.

Answer (score 4):

We have three working cases:

1) the computed value is required to initialize a `constexpr` value or where a compile-time-known value is strictly required (not-type template parameter, size of a C-style array, a test in a `static_assert()`, ...)

2) the `constexpr` function uses value not compile-time-known (by example: values received from standard input.

3) the `constexpr` function receive values compile-time-known but the result goes in a place not compile-time required.

If we ignore the as-if rule, we have that:

- in case (1) the compiler **must** compute the value compile-time because the computed value is required compile-time
- in case (2) the compiler **must** compute the value run-time because it's impossible compute it compile-time
- in case (3) we are in a grey area where the compiler can compute the value compile-time but the computed value isn't strictly required compile-time; in this case the compiler can choose if compute compile-time or run-time.

With the initial code

```
constexpr bool result = static_strcmp(a, b);
```

you are in case (1): the compiler **must** compute compile-time because the `result` variable is declared `constexpr`.

Removing the `constexpr`,

```
bool result = static_strcmp(a, b); // no more constexpr
```

your code translate in the grey area (case (3)), where compile-time computation is possible but not strictly required, because the input values are known compile time (`a` and `b`) but the result
goes where the value isn't compile-time required (an ordinary variable). So the compiler can choose and, in your case, choose the run-time computation with a version of the function, compile-time computation with another version.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior, because you always compare `strlen(a)` characters. The string `b` doesn't have that much characters.

If you modify your strings to be equal length (so your program becomes well-defined), your program will be [optimised](https://godbolt.org/z/tbJpl1) as you expect.

So this is not missed optimization. The compiler would optimize your program, but because it contains undefined behavior, it doesn't optimize it.

---

Note, that whether it is undefined behavior or not, is not super clear. Considering that the compiler uses `memcmp`, it thinks that both of the input strings must be at least `strlen(a)` long. So according to the behavior of the compiler, it is undefined behavior.

Here's what the current draft standard says about compare:

> *Returns*: 0 if for each i in [0, n), X::eq(p[i],q[i]) is `true`; else, a negative value if, for some j in [0, n), X::lt(p[j],q[j]) is `true` and for each i in [0, j) X::eq(p[i],q[i]) is `true`; else a positive value.

Now, it is not specified whether `compare` is allowed to read `p[j+1..n)` or `q[j+1..n)` (where `j` is the index of the first difference).